# Mock DNS server using Twisted

Tags: python, dns, twisted

I'm trying to write a Twisted-based mock DNS server to do some tests.

Taking inspiration from [this guide](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/18.9.0/names/howto/custom-server.html#a-server-which-computes-responses-dynamically) I wrote a very simple server that just resolves everything to `127.0.0.1`:

```py
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor
from twisted.names import dns, error, server


class MockDNSResolver:

    def _doDynamicResponse(self, query):
        name = query.name.name
        record = dns.Record_A(address=b"127.0.0.1")
        answer = dns.RRHeader(name=name, payload=record)
        authority = []
        additional = []
        return [answer], authority, additional

    def query(self, query, timeout=None):
        print("Incoming query for:", query.name)
        if query.type == dns.A:
            return defer.succeed(self._doDynamicResponse(query))
        else:
            return defer.fail(error.DomainError())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    clients = [MockDNSResolver()]
    factory = server.DNSServerFactory(clients=clients)
    protocol = dns.DNSDatagramProtocol(controller=factory)
    reactor.listenUDP(10053, protocol)
    reactor.listenTCP(10053, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

The above is working just fine with `dig` and `nslookup` (from a different terminal):

```
$ dig -p 10053 @localhost something.example.org A +short
127.0.0.1

$ nslookup something.else.example.org 127.0.0.1 -port=10053
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#10053

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   something.else.example.org
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

I'm also getting the corresponding hits on the terminal that's running the server:

```
Incoming query for: something.example.org
Incoming query for: something.else.example.org
```

Then, I wrote the following piece of code, based on [this section about making requests](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/18.9.0/web/howto/client.html#the-agent) and [this section about installing a custom resolver](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/18.9.0/names/howto/client-tour.html#installing-a-resolver-in-the-reactor):

```py
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.names.client import createResolver
from twisted.web.client import Agent


d = Agent(reactor).request(b'GET', b'http://does.not.exist')
reactor.installResolver(createResolver(servers=[('127.0.0.1', 10053)]))


def callback(result):
    print('Result:', result)


d.addBoth(callback)
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

reactor.run()
```

But this fails (and I get no lines in the server terminal). It appears as if the queries are not going to the mock server, but to the system-defined server:

```
Result: [Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError'>: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: does.not.exist.
/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/_resolver.py:137:deliverResults
/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py:921:resolutionComplete
/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:460:callback
/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:568:_startRunCallbacks
--- <exception caught here> ---
/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:654:_runCallbacks
/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py:975:startConnectionAttempts
]
```

I'm using:

- macOS 10.14.6 Python 3.6.6, Twisted 18.9.0
- Linux Mint 19.1, Python 3.6.9, Twisted 19.7.0

I appreciate any help, please let me know if additional information is required.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that if you replace `d.addBoth(callback)` with `d.addCallback(callback)` then you get the same behaviour. Right?

Comment: I get no output actually, because the deferred fails and there is no errback to handle it.

Comment: Look at my answer. It is working well. :)

Comment: Swapping the first two lines under `from twisted.web.client import Agent` makes the request actually go to your mock dns server. But then in the server we get `MockDNSResolver' object has no attribute 'lookupAllRecords'`

Comment: That's interesting, I thought the order didn't matter there because the reactor was not yet running. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The solution was:

- (Client) swap the order of the lines that install the resolver and create the deferred for the request, as suggested by @Hadus. I thought this didn't matter, since the reactor was not running yet.
- (Server) implement `lookupAllRecords`, reusing the existing `_doDynamicResponse` method.

```py
# server
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor
from twisted.names import dns, error, server


class MockDNSResolver:
    """
    Implements twisted.internet.interfaces.IResolver partially
    """

    def _doDynamicResponse(self, name):
        print("Resolving name:", name)
        record = dns.Record_A(address=b"127.0.0.1")
        answer = dns.RRHeader(name=name, payload=record)
        return [answer], [], []

    def query(self, query, timeout=None):
        if query.type == dns.A:
            return defer.succeed(self._doDynamicResponse(query.name.name))
        return defer.fail(error.DomainError())

    def lookupAllRecords(self, name, timeout=None):
        return defer.succeed(self._doDynamicResponse(name))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    clients = [MockDNSResolver()]
    factory = server.DNSServerFactory(clients=clients)
    protocol = dns.DNSDatagramProtocol(controller=factory)
    reactor.listenUDP(10053, protocol)
    reactor.listenTCP(10053, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

```py
# client
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.names.client import createResolver
from twisted.web.client import Agent


reactor.installResolver(createResolver(servers=[('127.0.0.1', 10053)]))
d = Agent(reactor).request(b'GET', b'http://does.not.exist:8000')


def callback(result):
    print('Result:', result)


d.addBoth(callback)
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

reactor.run()
```

```
$ python client.py
Result: <twisted.web._newclient.Response object at 0x101077f98>
```

(I'm running a simple web server with `python3 -m http.server` in another terminal, otherwise I get a reasonable `twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError` exception).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should make a request to it:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor

from twisted.names import client
resolver = client.createResolver(servers=[('127.0.0.1', 10053)])
d = resolver.getHostByName('does.not.exist')

def callback(result):
    print('Result:', result)

d.addBoth(callback)

reactor.callLater(4, reactor.stop)
reactor.run()
```

And the `MockDNSResolver`should be a subclass of `twisted.names.common.ResolverBase` and then you only have to implement `_lookup`.

```
class MockDNSResolver(common.ResolverBase):
    def _lookup(self, name, cls, type, timeout):
        print("Incoming query for:", name)
        record = dns.Record_A(address=b"127.0.0.5")
        answer = dns.RRHeader(name=name, payload=record)
        return defer.succeed(([answer], [], []))
```

Full code: https://pastebin.com/MfGahtAV

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not currently fitting my needs. I don't need to make standalone DNS requests, I need the reactor to query the local DNS server when resolving names for HTTP requests. Also, I'd prefer not to override "private" (underscored) methods.

Comment: `_lookup` is supposed to be overriden. Look at its code: `return defer.fail(NotImplementedError("ResolverBase._lookup"))` But anyway I see that you need a different answer...

Comment: "I need the reactor to query the local DNS server when resolving names for HTTP requests." Isn't that what my code is doing?

Comment: It is not, it's performing explicit standalone DNS requests by doing `resolver.getHostByName('does.not.exist')`

Comment: Regarding `_lookup`, I don't think it's supposed to be overriden by _external_ implementations. It's not exposed as part of the API, in fact it was removed from the docs, check https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.1.0/api/twisted.names.common.ResolverBase.html and https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/19.7.0/api/twisted.names.common.ResolverBase.html